# Using Nginx with Create-React-App dev server and npm start

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, create-react-app, nginx-config

Frustrating question here.  I have a react project created with created-react-app on a server that has to use Nginx for external connection/HTML server.  What essentially I need to do is use nginx as a proxy server and when the URL is typed into browser, the request is routed to localhost:3000 and the react app generates the result which is served to the client by nginx.

So, here is the nginx file so far, but I can't get it to work.  A number of questions:

1. does the root designation need to be directed to the /public directory in the react project to pick up index.html?
2. Assuming that you run `npm start` and after the compile, you enter the FQDN in the browser and it routes to localhost:3000

My Nginx config so far

```
    server_name         server-name.com;   
    listen              443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/site-name/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/site-name/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    proxy_read_timeout 60s;
    client_max_body_size 64M;
    
    # should this be routed to /public in the react project to pick up index.html?
    # root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        
        # Make sure React Application return is index.html so client routing remains in sync/reachable        
        #try_files $uri /index.html;
   
        proxy_pass  http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }    

    location /_api {
       rewrite ^/_api/(.+) /$1 break;
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3030;
    }
}

server {
    server_name         server-name.com   
    listen              80;

    allow 10.0.0.0/16;
    deny all;

    proxy_read_timeout 60s;
    client_max_body_size 64M;

    # Should this be routed to /public in the react project to pick up index.html?
    # root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        
        # Make sure React Application return is index.html so client routing remains in sync/reachable        
        try_files $uri /index.html;

    }    

    location /_api {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3030;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open your nginx file vi sites-enabled/default if you don't know how to do that let me know.

then remove everything from that file and simply paste :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    client_max_body_size 10M;
    server_name YourWebsiteNameWithDomain yourIPV4;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     }
}
```

don't forget to restart your nginx

Comment: Hi Sumit Thank you for suggestion. I am using Centos7 and don't have sites-enabled/default file.  I just have conf.d directory and my nginx-site.conf file.  Does this go inside there?